# Cannot find HTML a file in Laravel project

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I cloned a Laravel project off GitHub and navigated to a page which is for a cancellation policy. This is the code inside that file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Cancellation Policies |')
@section('description', '')
@section('keywords', '')

@section('content')
    <section id="section1" class="inr-bnr-sec">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-title1 center-align">
                <h1><span>Cancellation Policies</span></h1>
                <div>
                    <ul class="banr-breadcrumb">
                        <li><a href="{{url('/')}}">Home</a></li>
                        <li>Cancellation Policies</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="privcy-sec">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="prvcy-mn-cont">
                        {!! $page->meta_description !!}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@endsection
```

However on the webpage there is a load of text showing. Where the `{!! $page->meta_description !!}` statement is, I am assuming this is where the text is located yet I do not know where this code is, nor can I find the file where the code is.

Controller:

```
public function cancellation_policies(){
    $common_model = new Common();
    $page = $common_model->getfirst('pages',array( 'id' => '3'));
    return view('cancellation_policy')->with('page',$page);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding the github repository that you cloned, so we can help you further

Comment: It's a private repo for an internship I am doing, I don't think you'll be able to see it

Comment: Could you add the code for the controller this blade file is parsed by?

Comment: @JasperHelmich Added it bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OKay so your $page var is a Common() model

This corresponds with a table, there is probably a column name meta_description in that table.

If not there may be a method called getMetDescriptionAttribute on the model.

Maybe this gets your further?

Comment: You legend!! It was in the mySql Database!